# Laplace transform of integral with Heaviside function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform

I want to find the Laplace transform of 
$$f(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\sin(r)u(r-\beta)(t-r)^{\alpha} dr$$ for $\alpha,\, \beta > 0$ where $u$ is the unit step function. I don't understand what my approach should be here - I know that $$\mathcal{L}\{u(t-c)f(t-c)\}=e^{-sc}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\},$$ but I don't see how to convert the expression with the integral into the familiar form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $f(t) = \sin(t)u(t-\beta)\star t^\alpha$. Do you see where to go from here?

Edit: As a sanity check, your final answer should be:

$$ e^{-\beta s}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{s^{\alpha+1}}\frac{\cos(\beta)+s\sin(\beta)}{s^2+1}$$

Comment: Ah yes, the convolution... So I end up with $\mathcal{L}\{t^{\alpha}\}\mathcal{L}\{sin(t)u(t-\beta)\}$. But the formula I know for laplace transform of function multiplied with unit step function is $\mathcal{L}\{u(t-c)f(t-c)\} = e^{-sc}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$. My $sin(t)$ is unshifted, how do I simplify?

Comment: @novo What if it was already shifted, secretly? $\sin(t) = \sin((t-c)+c)$. Then all you would have to use is the angle addition formula.

Comment: Ok so $sin(t)*u(t-\beta) = sin((t-\beta)+\beta)*u(t-\beta)$. So what remains is really just finding $\mathcal{L}\{sin(t-\beta)cos(\beta)+sin(\beta)cos(t-\beta)\}$?
In the last term I use the addition formula for sine where $t-\beta$ is the first variable and $\beta$ the second

Comment: @novo yes that is correct

Comment: Thank you for the hints - I arrived at the same expression, but I don't entirely agree with your use of the gamma function - it is given that $\alpha, \beta > 0$, so I got $\frac{\alpha!}{s^{\alpha+1}}e^{-s\beta}\frac{cos(\beta)+s*sin(\beta)}{s^2+1}$

Comment: @novo $\alpha$ is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: Oh ok, so the only difference in the gamma function and the one I used is that the gamma function is valid for all numbers $>-1$? Why is the $-1$ neccesary? What happens below $-1$?

Comment: @novo $\Gamma$ has a pole at every negative integer. Regardless $\alpha !$ is wrong since $\alpha$ can be any positive real number.